# Hibernate transaction not successfully started

Tags: java, hibernate

Consider this simple Hibernate scenario:

```
session = getHibernateSession();
tx = session.beginTransaction();
SomeObject o = (SomeObject) session.get(SomeObject.class, objectId);
tx.commit();
```

This code produces the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:100)
    at com.bigco.package.Clazz.getSomeData(Clazz.java:1234)
```

What's going on?

Comment: Are you also using a transaction manager?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the configuration is, but supposing we do have a transaction manager, will that affect said behavior?

Comment: I've read that sometimes manually creating a transaction like you are with a transaction manager present will cause it to throw this exception.

Comment: This is a really good question and hard-to-believe answer. Why would Hibernate commit a transaction when an entity is retrieved via get(...)? I haven't been able to track down answers to this in Hb documentation yet. Is it because the get checks for underlying transaction and then uses that to do the SELECT and then commits it? I would like to see a much more detailed answer on this question.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Well, it looks like once we reach the `tx.commit()` line, the transaction has already been committed. My only guess is that Hibernate already commits the transaction when `get()`ing the object.

The fix for this is simple:

```
// commit only if tx still hasn't been committed yet (by hibernate)
if (!tx.wasCommitted())
    tx.commit();
```

Comment: The suggested solution worked for me. Would like to know though if there is a intelligent way to find where the transaction was committed ?

Answer (score 11):

This is a really old question and I figure you've already solved it (or given up on Hibernate) but the answer is tragically simple. I'm surprised no one else picked it up.

You haven't done a session.save(o), so there is nothing in the transaction to commit. The commit may still not work if you haven't changed anything in the object, but why would you want to save it if nothing has changed?

BTW: It is also perfectly acceptable to do the session.get(...) before the session.beginTransaction().

Comment: So, if I dont make changes to database, I shouldn't begin tx ?

Comment: I recommend using caution with this approach. I would think this is only acceptable with autocommit on, which Hibernate vigorously discourages. Without autocommit, everything MUST happen within a transaction - even single select statements.

Answer (score 9):

I got to know that this is already solved; even though I am posting my answer here.

I haven't found `wasCommitted()` method on the transaction.

But the following code worked for me:

```
// commit only, if tx still hasn't been committed yet by Hibernate
if (tx.getStatus().equals(TransactionStatus.ACTIVE)) { 
    tx.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One situation this can happen in is when the code is in an EJB/MDB using container-managed transactions (CMT), either intentionally or because it's the default. To use bean-managed transactions, add the following annotation:

@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)

There's more to it than that, but that's the beginning of the story.

Comment: Can you tell which package does @TransactionManagement belong?. I am unable to find it in my classpath

Comment: `javax.ejb.TransactionManagement`. See https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/TransactionManagement.html

Answer (score 0):

remove session.close(); from your program as few of the bigger transaction require more time and while closing the connection problem get occurred. use session.flus() only.

Comment: This answer does not seem to be in response to the particular question. There is no session.close()

Comment: I had the problem with "transaction not successfully started" today and the reason was that the session was closed.

Answer (score 0):

You should check weather you have used this session.getTransaction().commit();  or rollback command as higher version of hibernate removed manual code interaction by using
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly = false, rollbackFor = Exception.class) annotation you can avoid any transaction related exception.

Answer (score 0):

Above solutions were not helpful for me and that is why I want to share my solution.

In my case, I was not using @Column annotation properly in one of my entity. I changed my code from

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "false") 
private boolean isAvailable;
```

to

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "boolean default false") 
private boolean isAvailable;
```

And it worked.

My create method in dao

```
public int create(Item item) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    try {

          int savedId = (int) session.save(item);
          return savedId;
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          session.getTransaction().rollback();
          return 0; //==> handle in custom exception
        }
}
```