# Want to delete database value and document from folder in a single hibernate transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, file, transactions

I want to know is transaction applicable to document deletion with database query execution?I am new in hibernate query transaction.I want to delete a document details from the database table and at the same time particular document must be delete from the document.If there is no deletion takes place in document deletion, then does not occur the database value deletion wise versa.I think this can be done using transaction.Is this applicable?Or Is there any solution to my problem?I try with transaction code.But it shows Transaction not successfully started Exception.

Thank you

In my DAOHibernateImplimentation class

```
getHibernateTemplate().execute(new HibernateCallback() {
public Object doInHibernate(final Session session)throws HibernateException, java.sql.SQLException {

Transaction tx = null;
int deleteStatus=0;
try {
    tx = session.beginTransaction();
    final String deleteQuery = "delete from tablename where name='"+name+"'";                                       
    deleteStatus = (Integer)getHibernateTemplate().execute(new HibernateCallback(){
    public Object doInHibernate(final Session session) throws HibernateException, java.sql.SQLException
    {
    Query query = session.createSQLQuery(deleteQuery);                                              
    return query.executeUpdate();
    }
      });
    if(deleteStatus>0){
        file.delete();
        }   
     tx.commit();                                                                        
    } catch (Exception e) {
            tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
                }       
                return deleteStatus;    
    }

});
```

Exception is:

```
17:09:30,447 ERROR [STDERR] org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit      Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException:    Transaction not successfully started
17:09:30,447 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:562)
17:09:30,447 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:662)
17:09:30,447 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:632)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with TransactionTemplate

```
TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate=new TransactionTemplate();
transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback() {
    @Override
    public Object doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {
    int deleteStatus = 0;
        try {
   final String deleteQuery = "delete from tablename where name='" + name + "'";
   deleteStatus = (Integer) getHibernateTemplate().execute(new HibernateCallback() {
   public Object doInHibernate(final Session session) throws HibernateException, java.sql.SQLException {
   Query query = session.createSQLQuery(deleteQuery);
   return query.executeUpdate();
         }
     });
 if (deleteStatus > 0) {
       file.delete();
        }
 } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
       }
     return deleteStatus;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the `getHibernateTemplate().execute ...` is not executed in the Transaction. Like described here [Hibernate transaction not successfully started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155039/hibernate-transaction-not-successfully-started) there might be nothing to commit. I suggest you to remove the `HibernateCallback` and just directly execute the query.

Edit. Like this!

```
getHibernateTemplate().execute(new HibernateCallback() {
public Object doInHibernate(final Session session)throws HibernateException, java.sql.SQLException {

  Transaction tx = null;
  int deleteStatus=0;
  try {
      tx = session.beginTransaction();
      final String deleteQuery = "delete from tablename where name='"+name+"'";                                       

      Query query = session.createSQLQuery(deleteQuery);                                              
      deleteStatus = query.executeUpdate();

      if(deleteStatus>0){
          boolean deleted = file.delete();
          if(!deleted)
             throw new IOException("Error deleting");
       }   
       tx.commit();                                                                        
  } catch (Exception e) {
      tx.rollback();
      e.printStackTrace();
  }       
  return deleteStatus;    


});
```

You need to check the return value of the file.delete() call. (See JavaDoc)

Comment: But I want to delete database value and document from folder in a single hibernate transaction.Is transaction work after HibernateCall back removal?