# (org.hibernate.TransactionException) org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, exception

How to use the same method multiple times?

```
    public boolean updateQuery(String sql) {
    Session session = null;
    Transaction transaction = null;
    boolean flag = false;
    SQLQuery query;
    try {
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        transaction = (Transaction) session.beginTransaction();
        query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
        query.executeUpdate();
        transaction.commit();
        flag = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        flag = false;
        LOGGER.error(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        if (transaction != null) {
            transaction.rollback();
        }
        return false;
    } finally {
        if (session != null) {
            session.close();
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

When i use **updateQuery** method for the first time it runs fine without any exception. But when the same method is called the second time it gives an exception saying **" (org.hibernate.TransactionException) org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started"**
Could anyone help me out in how to fix the issue.

Comment: Post the full stack trace. Post your configs for hibernate/spring.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155039/hibernate-transaction-not-successfully-started